# Using bash variables in Github API v4

Tags: json, git, github, graphql

Github seems to allow variables in its API v4. This is what I wanted to use in bash to transfer a number between two queries:

- The first query gets the number of the last closed PR.

```
{
  "query": "query getLatestPulLRequests {
  search(query: "repo:<owner>/<repo> type:pr is:open sort:updated-desc", type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        number
        id
        title
        mergedAt
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
  }"
}
```

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" -d @./scripts/queries/gitqueryClosedPRsByDate.json https://github.ibm.com/api/graphql | jq .data.search.nodes[0].number > latestPRnumber.json
```

This works beautifully and gives me the right number back. I can also just parse it into a variable (which I tried).

- The second query is supposed to call the PR with the latestPRnumber and queries the title, body and all comments from it.

```
{
  "query": "query getPrTitleBodyComments{
  repository(name: "<repo>", owner: "<owner>") {
    id
    pullRequest(number: 1) {
      number
      title
      body
      comments(last: 10) {
        totalCount
        nodes {
          body
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }"
}
```

The second query with the number static works fine as well.

!!!
But instead of the manual number `pullRequest(number: 1)` in query 2, I want to use the `latestPRnumber`. Does anyone have an idea, how I can do that in bash?

- I tried adding `"variables": {"PRnumber": "$PRnumber"}`in the JSON but since its not a script it obviously doesn't work. Can I include the variable in the `curl` somehow?
- I tried

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" -d @./scripts/queries/gitqueryClosedPRsByDate.json -d 'PRnumber=$PRnumber'  https://github.ibm.com/api/graphql | jq .
```

(passing it as more data) but the ERROR is always the same:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   409  100   115  100   294    219    560 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   779
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.21/v4"
}
```

Comment: start with passing repo name in variables .... variables must be jsoned ... search SO for some curl examples/syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL queries can include [variables](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables).  These need to be declared at the top level of your query, and then can be used anywhere inside the query:

```graphql
query GetPrTitleBodyComments($repo: String!, $owner: String!, $prNumber: Int!) {
  repository(name: $repo, owner: $owner) {
    pullRequest(number: $prNumber) { ... }
  }
}
```

In the [JSON request format](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) you need to pass `"variables"` as a separate top-level item, alongside the `"query"`:

```json
{
  "query": "query GetPrTitleBodyComments(...) { ... }",
  "variables": {
    "repo": "<repo>",
    "owner": "<owner>",
    "prNumber": 1
  }
}
```

Assembling this in a shell script can be a little bit tricky.  (A higher-level scripting language with a [GraphQL client library](https://graphql.org/code/) might be a better match.)  The curl `-d` [option](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) can use the conventional `-` as a filename to read the input data from stdin, so you can structure the overall shell request as

```sh
(something to generate the request JSON) | \
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
  --data-binary @- \
  https://github.ibm.com/api/graphql | \
jq -r .data.repository.pullRequest.title
```

If you're already using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) then you can use it to safely assembly the JSON file.  The tricks here are that `jq --arg key value` sets `$key` to some value; `jq --rawfile key filename` sets `$key` to the contents of `filename`; and `jq -f file.jq` reads the jq filter (program) from a file.  So you can write a jq "program" like:

```
{
  query: $query,
  variables: {
    repo: $repo,
    owner: $owner,
    prNumber: $prNumber
  }
}
```

and then invoke this as

```sh
jq -f ./scripts/queries/gitqueryClosedPRsByDate.jq \
  --rawfile query ./scripts/queries/gitqueryClosedPRsByDate.json \
  --arg repo '<repo>' \
  --arg owner '<owner>' \
  --arg prNumber 1 | \
curl ... --data-binary @- ...
```

Using `jq` this way ensures the JSON is syntactically correct and protects you against unusual characters being embedded in the variable values.  In principle you could assemble the JSON query as a string, perhaps using a `<<` heredoc, but it's up to you to make sure the query variables don't contain double-quotes, newlines, or other things that would disrupt the JSON structure.

(And once again, a GraphQL client library in a higher-level language will manage all of these details for you: you can generally pass it the query as a fixed string, the variables as a dictionary or map object, and the API URL, and it will take care of all of this formatting for you.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for and should be in the Github API documentation!!

Comment: on thing that still stands out for me is that you can easily add a variable to the second query since it has no double quotes.
But in the query that has `search(query: "repo: <repo>")` I find it hard to add a variable. I can't figure out how to escape the variable properly. I tried `search(query: "repo: \"$repo\" ")` but it says:
Variable "$repo" is never used in the operation. Any ideas on how to make this optimisation work?

Answer (score 0):

@David-maze had the perfect solution for the problem. I also discovered that in some cases you may combine queries instead. This could impact performance but makes data handling easier. In my case I came up with this:

```
query getLatestPulLRequests {
  search(query: "repo:<owner>/<repo> type:pr is:open sort:updated-desc", type: ISSUE, first: 10) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        number
        id
        title
        mergedAt
        updatedAt
        body
        comments(last: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              author {
                login
              }
              body
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which results in:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0NTMwNjQ0MzQ0",
          "title": "This is the PR Title",
          "mergedAt": null,
          "updatedAt": "2020-12-02T18:33:16Z",
          "body": "This is the description of the PR",
          "comments": {
            "edges": [
              {
                "node": {
                  "author": {
                    "login": "<user>"
                  },
                  "body": "this is the first comment"
                }},
              {
                "node": {
                  "author": {
                    "login": "<user>"
                  },
                  "body": "this is the second comment"
              } }
            ]
        } }
      ]
} } }
```

Comment: https://github.community/t/using-bash-variables-in-github-api-v4-queries-transferring-query-results/147072/3?u=janniksinz

Comment: combining ... graphql designed for this kind of freedom .... still variables (`$query` and `$limit`) should be used ... easier to adapt/modify ... variable can be undefined widhout query modification

Comment: good point @xadm. I am actually trying to implement a travis variable which stores the Repo information.
`search(query: " repo: $TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG " )` However I am not sure if that is possible because of the quotation. It makes it even more difficult being in a JSON file:---------------------------------------
{
  "query": "query getLatestPulLRequests {\n  search(query: \"repo:EA/mdmx-job-ms type:pr is:closed sort:merged-desc\", type: ISSUE, last: 10) 

{nodes} }"
}